# Random movement with turtle

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-turtle

I want it to take the current x and y coordinates and pick either x ± 10 or y ± 10 and go there, but i keep getting `TypeError: turtle.Vec2D() argument after * must be an iterable, not float`

This my the code:

```
from turtle import Screen
import turtle, random, time
turtle.speed(1)
goto = [
    turtle.xcor() + 10,
    turtle.xcor() - 10,
    turtle.ycor() + 10,
    turtle.ycor() - 10
]
turtle.goto(goto[random.randint(0,3)])
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is exactly what the error message says. You are passing a number when you are supposed to pass a pair of coordinates or a `Vec2D`. From the [goto documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.goto):

> Parameters
>
> x – a number or a pair/vector of numbers>
>
> y – a number or None
>
> If y is None, x must be a pair of coordinates or a Vec2D (e.g. as
> returned by pos()).

Currently you are only passing `x`, since all the values in your goto array are numbers. Therefore, `y` is the default value `None`.

Here is a fixed version:

```
nextPos = [
    (turtle.xcor() + 10, turtle.ycor()),
    (turtle.xcor() - 10, turtle.ycor()),
    (turtle.xcor(), turtle.ycor() + 10),
    (turtle.xcor(), turtle.ycor() - 10)
]

turtle.goto(nextPos[random.randint(0,3)])
```

[[Try it out here]](https://trinket.io/python/9fc1d1b564)

(PS: I recomend renaming the array to make the code easier to understand)